# DHCP for USB virtual ethernet interface

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I'm attempting to connect my [Arietta G25](http://www.acmesystems.it/arietta) Debian ARM board to my home network using DHCP (or failing that, a static IP in the correct subnet). I'm currently using the board over USB, which shows up as some kind of virtual Ethernet interface which is configured using a static `192.168.10.0/24` IP. I can access it (SSH) from the machine it's plugged into, but I want to be able to access the rest of my network on `192.168.1.0/24` and the internet from the board, as well as access the board from my home network.

The home network is on the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet.

Currently, I have two `/etc/network/interfaces` files:

**Host config** (Linux host box)

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**Board config** (Debian ARM board over USB)

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.10.20
```

I've tried setting the board's IP to `192.168.1.90` but that made it unaccessible. Something to do with the gateway perhaps? I've also tried

```
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

to no avail.

How can I get my USB-connected-with-virtual-ethernet-interface ARM board to have an IP address (DHCP or static) on the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet used by the rest of my network when plugged into a box over USB? I'd prefer to use DHCP. There is a DHCP server running on the router on `192.168.1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using NAT and iptables (thanks to Greg Bowser's answer for inspiration). Assuming `eth0` is the network interface and `usb0` is the Arietta's network interface, this will set up routing on the host **temporarily**:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o usb0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Give it a test (might need to `ifdown usb0` and `ifup usb0` or reboot the Arietta). If the rules work, you should be able to ping an external address (`192.168.1.1` or `google.com` perhaps) from the Arietta.

If the above iptables rules work, you can make them **permanent** by adding `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and saving the iptables rules. I did this by installing `iptables-persistent` (`apt-get install iptables-persistent`) and saving the rules during installation.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the board's IP to `192.168.1.90` will not work because routing will fail. If you run `ip route` on the host box, it will show that `192.168.1.0/24` is connected via your normal network connection to the rest of the LAN. It is trying to route packets out that interface and not `usb0` as intended.

Two options:

1. Use the Linux host as a router. This requires enabling forwarding and setting up NAT (MASQUERADING) with  iptables (this is actually pretty simple)
2. Create a bridge interface on your host box and add both of the physical interfaces to that bridge. This is basically like connecting them both to the same switch, but done in software. I will assume your network is connected to the host box on `eth0`:

   ```
   brctl addbr br0
   brctl addif br0 usb0
   brctl addif eth0
   ```

This should Just Work©. You may need to install the `bridge-utils` package. Since you're using a Debian-based distro, [see here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried creating a bridge which unfortunately made the board completely inaccessible for some reason, however I managed to set up some NAT rules in my `iptables` config which worked

Comment: :). This may not have been your issue, but I also should have added that the bridge would not work over wireless. In any case, glad to hear you got it working.